# is site to site better than vpn client?

Tags: site-to-site-vpn

There has a branch in another country and I want to connected it with my office using vpn:

my question is:
is site to site better than vpn client ?

The most important thing to be a safer and easy.

Thanks

Comment: Please try to explain better what you are trying to do, and how.

Comment: Site-to-Site **is** a vpn client. You would need to be much more specific about the technologies you are considering and your scenario in order to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that's easy and secure for your remote office then I would always suggest a site-to-site VPN is the preferred option.

Effectively you're extending your network onto both sites, with the users not having to worry about special configuration settings on their devices and their devices gaining any/all benefits of your LAN while on the network (e.g. AV and OS updates from any local update server (well "local" is perhaps the wrong word as its a remote site, but I mean a service that your business controls), centrally managed policy settings, etc, filtered web proxy servers if you use them, etc.

I'd personally only consider a client VPN solution for people who are working from home or who travel from place to place for the business.